# Module parse error in 'pdfjs-dist' module in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, pdf

Following error is obtained when trying to build project using 'pdfjs-dist' npm module in Angular

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (2413:45)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/babel/webpack-loader.js
 * ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|         intent: renderingIntent,
|         renderInteractiveForms: renderInteractiveForms === true,
>         annotationStorage: annotationStorage?.getAll() || null
|       });
|     }
```

How to resolve this?
Any workarounds or suggestions would help a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error can be fixed by downgrading the version of 'pdfjs-dist' module version from 2.7.570 to a lower stable version say 2.5.207.

Another fix could be upgrading the version of webpack from 4.x to 5.x, but this is not a recommended solution as this can create issues with the other dependent modules of the project.

Answer (score 0):

I had encountered the same error. This worked for me, might work for you

-----------use these lines---------

```
"fileReplacements": [
       {
                "replace": "./node_modules/jspdf/dist/jspdf.es.min.js",
                "with": "./node_modules/jspdf/dist/jspdf.umd.min.js"
              }
],
```

In angular.json file,

```
"build": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
    "options": {
place the above code here....
........
}
```

Comment: The package you are mentioning, jspdf, is something different than pdfjs. Those files aren't present in pdfjs-dist.